# How to loop background music without lag/delay when song repeats (seamless)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, avfoundation

I am trying to make a game with background music looping in it. I made the song file in Adobe Audition (which is similar to audacity) and when I play it in a loop in Adobe Audition it loops how I want it.

When I play it in Xcode however, it has a lag in between the loops. I am using AVFoundations for the sound playing.

I have searched everywhere but I can't find the solution for the problem.

Is there any way you can loop audio files without there being any lags in between ? (I believe its called "seamless looping" )

here is the code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
...// Other Code

var ButtonAudio = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Gamescene(new)", ofType: "mp3")!)
var ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

... //Other Code

}
```

And When I Call it:

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    ...//Code

    ButtonAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: ButtonAudio, fileTypeHint: nil)
    ButtonAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    ButtonAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    ButtonAudioPlayer.play()

    ...//More Code
    }
```

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Apple‘s web site has a bit of sample code that shows how one loops playback. Basically, you need to use an AVQueuePlayer and queue up the same song again before the previous one has finished playing. The code uses a Looper class for this.

Comment: Try putting a **number of loops** and after `ButtonAudioPlayer.play()`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AVPlayerLooper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper) and [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer) to do this.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer()
    var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Gamescene(new)", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(url: url))
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
        queuePlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I believe the device needs to be at least IOS 10 in order to use AVPlayerLooper. And my app targets IOS 8, Correct? Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Is there a way to do it with AVQueuePlayer alone ?

Comment: I searched online and I saw that over 90% of iPhones are in IOS 10 or above so I think it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by [@dave234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313967/dave234) only works in iOS > 10. Since I needed to make seamless playback in iOS > 9, I did something different:

1. Instead of `AVPlayer`, I created `AVQueuePlayer` and immediately added two identical melodies to the queue.
2. Next, I made a listener to the penultimate melody.
3. When the listener was triggered, I added another similar record to the queue after the last one.

In fact, in order to avoid delay, I always play the penultimate record.

**My code:**

```
var player: AVQueuePlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "music_file", ofType: "mp3") {
        player = createPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    }
}

func createPlayer(url: URL) -> AVQueuePlayer {
    let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: [AVPlayerItem(url: url), AVPlayerItem(url: url)])
    loopPlayer(playerItem: player.items()[player.items().count - 2])
    return player
}

func loopPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        if let player = self.player, let url = (playerItem.asset as? AVURLAsset)?.url {
            player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: player.items()[player.items().count - 1])
            self.loopPlayer(playerItem: player.items()[player.items().count - 2])
        }
    }
}
```